# How to use CryptoJS CTR mode with variable message size (nonce counter & offset)

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs, nonce

When using cryptoJS to encrypt and decrypt messages in AES (CTR mode), the AES algorithm relies on a nonce (Number Once) value to muddle up your stream block and prevent replay attacks. In cryptoJS, to set your nonce up:

```
  const cli_verify = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(originalString), key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
  });
```

Similarly, you can use the same approach when you decrypt your messages:

```
  const decryptedString = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedStringB64, key, {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
  }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);
```

BUT: if you do this, you need to track the nonce yourself. Which is a) a pain, and b) really difficult if you start dealing with messages of variable sizes (i.e. not a multiple of 16 bytes).

I've pulled apart the AES library that I'm talking to on the other side, and figured out how the nonce counter and offset work. Basically, if you start sending very small messagaes, like 4 bytes for example, the 4 bytes will be decrypted using hte first 4 bytes of the stream and an offset will be incremented to 4 to keep track of this. If 6 bytes are then encrypted, the next 6 bytes of the stream are used (without incrementing the nonce), and the offset is updated to 10... If the next transmission is 143 bytes, you can see how this starts to get complicated to implement yourself. The last 6 bytes of the current stream are used, the nonce is increased and so on.

My question is: how to get CryptoJS to handle this for you during a session. I've tried setting the IV, padding and mode in the first invocation, and then leaving it blank in the next, but it doesn't work. Its an awesome library, and I'm sure it's in there. It's just not obvious how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the progressive ciphering api instead, this does update the nonce/counter correctly.

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f");
    
// encrypt
var aesEncryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createEncryptor(key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
});
var ciphertextPart1 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 1");
var ciphertextPart2 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 2");
var ciphertextPart3 = aesEncryptor.process("Message Part 3");
var ciphertextPart4 = aesEncryptor.finalize();
    ​
// decrypt
var aesDecryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createDecryptor(key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
});    ​

var plaintextPart1 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart1);
var plaintextPart2 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart2);
var plaintextPart3 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart3);
var plaintextPart4 = aesDecryptor.process(ciphertextPart4);
var plaintextPart5 = aesDecryptor.finalize();
```

As per https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/ where the above snippet was originally taken from.

If you process inputs that do not match the block size (as in your case) you will not get all of the output until you call finalize.

You may find that you need to call finalize to get the output from an input that does not match the block size but still wish to keep using the encryptor/decryptor. The usecase for this is where the nonce needs to be synchronised between client and server. The api does not work if you call process after finalize when input and blocksize are mismatched. The clone api does not work correctly either with mismatch blocksize and input (which is effectively what you would want to do in this case).

However if you keep track of all input sent and received during the session you are able to reconstitute the session after calling finalize. This can be done by replaying the previous inputs into a new encryptor/decryptor by calling process before calling finalize to get the final output. In this case after you call finalize you need to take the same number of bytes from the output as there were in the input as the encryptor/decryptor may contain some previous output as is the case with input blocksize mismatch.